# Xamarin forms how to keep label text after label animation

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, label, xamarin.forms

I would like to figure out, how to keep my label text appear after label animation completion. My idea is that I have Label on top and Entry field behind it. Until there isn't any text in entry, my label is empty, but when I starting to type my label appear with animation over and over after each newly typed character. I already did that, but I wan't that it will appear with animation one time, and then keep showing my regular label without repeating animation. Because now my label shows with animation and do no keep, it disappears immediately.

Here is my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Project.MyPage">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="7,7,7,7" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">
              <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White">
              <Label x:Name="NameText"  />
              <Entry x:Name="Name"  />
              </StackLayout>                    
    </StackLayout>  
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and here is my C# code with EventHandler: TextChange

```
public MyPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Name.TextChanged += Name_TextChanged;
}
private async void Name_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
   NameText.Animate("nameAnimation", new Animation(v => NameText.Scale = v, 1, 2, Easing.SpringIn));
   NameText.Text = "MyLabel";
}
```

How to my label appear and complete animation action only one time?
Thank you for answers or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Detach your handler after the animation:

```cs
async void Name_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  NameText.Animate("nameAnimation", new Animation(v => NameText.Scale = v, 1, 2, Easing.SpringIn));
  NameText.Text = "MyLabel";
  Name.TextChanged -= Name_TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: Now animation show one time and label do not keep show text. I see blank label after animation and my visual studio restarting when I add'ed `-= Name_TextChanged;`